# R - reshape dataframe from duplicated column names but unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2, tidyr

Hi I have a dataframe that looks like the following

[image]

I want to apply a function to it so that it reshapes it like this

[image]

How would I do that?

Comment: Honestly, it's best to deal with duplicate column names upstream so they don't occur in the first place. Here, `rbind` the two subsets together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option that could work.  W loop through the `unique` `names` of the dataset, create a logical index with `==`, extract the columns, `unlist`, create a `data.frame`, and then `cbind` it together or just use `data.frame` (assumption is that the number of duplicate elements are equal for each set)

```
 data.frame(lapply(unique(names(df1)), function(x)
     setNames(data.frame(unlist(df1[names(df1)==x], use.names = FALSE)), x)))
#  type model make
#1    a     b    c
#2    d     e    f
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(type = "a", model = "b", make = "c", type = "d",
      model = "e",
      make = "f", check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```